# Multiple pipe implementation not working in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to implement multiple pipes in C. This is the main part of the function that takes care of piping

```
ProcesscommandwithPipes()
{
............................

for (k=0; k <= num_of_pipes; k++)
   {

      read[k]= -1;
      write[k] = -1;
   }
   //create required number of pipes
    for(j=0; j < num_of_pipes; j++)
    {
       if( pipe(fd) == -1 )
       {
          perror("Pipe failure");
          return;
       }
       read[j+1] = fd[0];
       write[j] = fd[1];
    }


    for(k=0; k<= num_of_pipes; k++)
    {

      pid = fork();

      if(pid < 0 )
      {
         printf("fork failed\n");
      }
      else if (pid == 0)
      {
            if(write[k] != -1)
         {

            if( dup2(write[k],1) == -1){
            perror("dup2 error");
            exit(1);}
         }

        if(read[k] != -1)
         {

            if( dup2(read[k],0) == -1)
            {
              perror("dup2read  error");
              exit(1);
            }
         }

        for (h=0; h<= num_of_pipes;h++)
        {
              close(write[h]);
              close(read[h]);
        }


          if(execvp((const char*)commandArgv[k][0], commandArgv[k]) < 1)
          {
            perror("error");
            exit(1);
          }

        exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        processid[k] = pid;

        printf("waiting on process:%d\n", processid[k]);
        close(write[k]);
        close(read[k]);
        waitpid(processid[k], &status, 0);

       }
     }
```

For some reason, the following command works fine
**ls|grep tmp|sort**

But the following command doesn't work, although it is pretty much the same
**cat tmp1.out|grep tmp|sort**

(tmp1.out contains the list of the files in the cur dir, same as the output of ls)
There is no error message too.But it just exits without printing anything on screen(though the stdout of the last command is not changed)

P.S: **cat tmp1.out|grep tmp** works fine too.

contents of tmp1.out:
a.out
sample
shell.c
tmp1.out
tmp.out
b.c

Any inputs?

Comment: Study the source code of existing free software shells like `sash` and `bash`. Also, `strace -f` them to understand the involved syscalls. Also, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/]

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to write a shell, but have you considered using popen?

FILE *p = popen("cat tmp1.out|grep tmp|sort", "r");

Comment: It is very probably a homework, so I don't think that a solution involvling `system`, `popen` and/or `/bin/sh` fits the bill.

Comment: yeah. I want to get the input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you call `waitpid()` within your loop and thus you won't start the second process before the first one terminates. But now the first one could hang if the pipe buffer size is reached and you have a deadlock or a process might be killed  by a broken pipe. Besides, `for(k=0; k<= num_of_pipes; k++)` looks strange to me, because that loops `num_of_pipes+1` times

Comment: The waitpid() is executed by the parent and the reason I have that way is because, I want the parent to wait for the first command to be executed.  Also the for loops num_of_pipes+1 times, since there are num_of_pipes+1 commands(one process for each command). I hope am clear. What confuses me is the command ls|grep tmp|sort works fine :(

Comment: normally the two sides of the pipe should run simultanously. I still think the problem might be that in your case they don't. And different programs may react differently if that is really the problem. I would just call `waitpid()` in for all `processid[k]` another loop after you have started all your children and see what happens.

Comment: Tried it that way. Added a separate for loop to wait on child processes, after the for(k=0...). Still no luck :(

Comment: too bad, it was a guess... I have no other idea at the moment, but I will think about ist